# Pointers in method params - objective-c

Tags: objective-c, pointers, parameters

How to pass pointer as param in method? 
for example:

```
-(void) dosomething:(NSString *) simpleString :(NSMutableArray *) pointerToArray;
```

where simpleString is simple param, and pointerToArray is pointer to an array;

Comment: All object variables are already pointers. What exactly do you want to accomplish with your method?

Answer (score 4):

In Objective-C, strings and arrays are both classes. As you can see, they are already accessed through pointers. So you simply use them as the declaration says:

```
-(void) dosomething:(NSString *) simpleString :(NSMutableArray *) pointerToArray;
```

And you invoke like:

```
NSString *s = @"Hello, world";
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Hello", @"silly", @"example", nil];

[yourClass dosomething:s :a];
```

---

FWIW, the name of your method is `dosomething::`. It is customary to denote each parameter, so I would call it:

```
-(void) doSomethingWithString:(NSString *)greeting array:(NSMutableArray *)strings;
```

then the name is `doSomethingWithString:array:` which is much more readable, IMO. You
invoke it with:

```
[yourClass doSomethingWithString:s array:a];
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
-(void) dosomething:(NSString *) simpleString :(NSMutableArray **) pointerToArray;
```

(Add a second '*' to the parameter type

In your method, you then do something like:

```
*pointerToArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: `NSMutableArray *` is already pointer. `NSMutableArray **` is pointer to pointer to array =)

Comment: Hmm, that's true. Well noted. I'm not sure I understood the OP's question. Still not sure I do! :P

Comment: I think, he doesn't understand that NSString* is already pointer.

Comment: Note that you should pretty much never have a method that returns void *and* takes a ** arg.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
NSString *localSimpleString;
NSMutableArray *localArray;
[self dosomething:localSimpleString :pointerToArray];
```